# Javascript - GPS DMS format to Decimal format function

Tags: javascript, gps, converters

I have searched around for a javascript function that can parse GPS data which is in DMS format to Decimal format. I have come up with little help, which mostly is due to the fact that the GPS data that I have is in a weird format.

```
My Data;
3550.192270N, 01432.026391E
Format;
ddmm.mmmmmmN, ddmm.mmmmmmE
```

I want to convert these values into latitude and longitude decimal format.

Thanks in advance,
Jean

Comment: not sure what you're looking for here. There seems to be a lot of resources on the web to convert this. I can help you with the javascript if you need it. I'm a little confused by the data though. Is that 3550.192270 supposed to indicate a degree measure of 3550? Or does it indicate a degree measure of 35?

Comment: The format that was provided for me was "ddmm.mmmmmm" I assumed that meant d = days, m = minutes. After I checked the output from the answer I provided I was apparently right. This was more confusing than challenging due to this unusual format and the assumptions I had to make. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct as I cannot do that since I posted it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**
Found a function online that is similar to my needs and converted it into accepting days and minutes only.

```
function ConvertDMSToDD(days, minutes) {
   var dd = days + minutes / 60;
   return dd;
}
```

*I'm using this function to convert data that I fetch from an Arduino shield with a GPS module.*

Comment: Tnx for awnsering your own question. I made a converter to a nmea output: '$GPRMC' to decimal. http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/2dykuvzw/41/. Maybe it's helpfull for someone :D. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

> Javascript - DMS string to Decimal format function

```
var dmsStr = "40° 19′ 22.81″ N 49° 19′ 15.61″ E";
var dmsToLonLatRegex= /[-]{0,1}[\d.]*[\d]|([NSEW])+/g;
var dmsParsed = dmsStr.match(dmsToLonLatRegex);
>Result => ["40", "19", "22.81", "N", "49", "19", "15.61", "E"];



    var dmsParsedObj = {
        latitude: {
            degree: dmsParsed[0],
            minute: dmsParsed[1],
            second: dmsParsed[2],
            direction: dmsParsed[3]
        },
        longitude: {
            degree: dmsParsed[4],
            minute: dmsParsed[5],
            second: dmsParsed[6],
            direction: dmsParsed[7]
        }
    }


    var dmsToLonLat = function (o) {
        var n = NaN;
        if (o) {
            var t = Number(o.degree),
                d = "undefined" != typeof o.minute ? Number(o.minute) / 60 : 0,
                l = "undefined" != typeof o.second ? Number(o.second) / 3600 : 0,
                r = o.direction || null;
            null !== r && /[SW]/i.test(r) && (t = -1 * Math.abs(t)), n = 0 > t ? t - d - l : t + d + l
        }
        return n
    }

var lonLat = [dmsToLonLat(dmsParsedObj.latitude), dmsToLonLat(dmsParsedObj.longitude)];
> Result => [49.321, 40.323]
```